# When does thread die in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, jvm, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, executor

Problem:
I wanted to know when a RunTimeException is thrown in run method of thread, will thread local of that thread be preserved? Answer to this question lies in what I'm asking below. So with that said, if thread dies(when exception is thrown) it's thread local snapshot get's cleared up or if thread does not die what happens to thread local in that case. Do we need to programmatically handle that?
Scenario:
During heavy load, request came in and processing took way too long and before response was created, async context times out. What happens in this scenario? What happens to the thread that is processing the request?

Here's more details :
I've been researching on how ThreadPoolExecutors internally work. What I'm curious to know is what happens when a RunTimeException is thrown in run method of thread. Does it get killed and ThreadPoolExecutor ends up creating brand new thread? Or JVM somehow does not let that thread to die, so that it can reused in 
the pool. I think the thread dies and so does it's ThreadLocal snapshot. 
I wanted to get some insight on exactly how ThreadPoolExecutor handle exceptions and how life cycle of a particular thread revolves around that.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you care about such implementation details? Worry about the interface, not the implementation. If you really care, you should dig into the code yourself. StackOverflow is for asking about problems you are having. Breaking down the implementation of every module in the JDK due to curiousity and not due to problems leads to clutter. This is a site to *get help with problems that lead to unexpected or unexplained results*.

Comment: *"I've been researching on how ThreadPoolExecutors internally work."* - so I assume you've read the sourcecode which ships with the JDK. Which part of the source did you have difficulty with?

Comment: This is in the source code for the runWorker method.

Comment: Thanks @NathanHughes. I've updated description to provide motive behind asking the question, so that folks don't think it's a clutter.

Comment: @Coder I didn't mean to offend. I understand new users think StackOverflow is for *anything* programming related, when the actual intention is to help developers progress pass roadblocks, or to understand surprising results. This question still presents no problems, so my comment still stands. Like I said, do you expect us to break down a JDK module anytime someone asks? What makes understanding this module any more important than understanding how other modules work? Feel free to post if you have a problem. If you are curious on how it works, why don't you study the source code yourself?

Comment: The life cycle of a thread is configurable, so even without exceptions, threads may die right after processing a task. And there is no unique treatment of exceptional cases, e.g. usually you use `submit` for new tasks which makes `FutureTask` responsible for that, as [note here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.Throwable-): “*When actions are enclosed in tasks (such as `FutureTask`) … these task objects catch and maintain computational exceptions, and so they do not cause abrupt termination*, …”

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Holger. Thanks everyone! I got my answer. Thread dies when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I got my answer.

Thread dies when an exception is thrown. Only catch here is if we reference a thread id in thread local that can cause a thread leak if that is not cleared properly.

Thread id can be reused as per java docs. In my case I was putting putting some stuff in thread local referencing to thread id (Thread.currentThread.getId). Best way to clear that up is to override  afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable, java.lang.Throwable) and clean up things in there.

From java docs:

```
    public long getId()
    Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.
```